# change seq name in a fasta file with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fasta

I got a problem, I explain the point.

I have one fasta file such:

```
>seqA
AAAAATTTGG
>seqB
ATTGGGCCG
>seqC
ATTGGCC
>seqD
ATTGGACAG
```

and a dataframe :

```
seq name      New name seq
seqB            BOBO
seqC            JOHN
```

and I simpy want to change my ID seq name in the fasta file if there is the same seq name in my dataframe and change it to the new name seq, it would give:

New fasta fil:

```
>seqA
AAAAATTTGG
>BOBO
ATTGGGCCG
>JOHN
ATTGGCC
>seqD
ATTGGACAG
```

Thank you very much

edit:
I used this script:

```
blast=pd.read_table("matches_Busco_0035_0042.m8",header=None)
blast.columns = ["qseqid", "Busco_ID", "pident", "length", "mismatch", "gapopen","qstart", "qend", "sstart", "send", "evalue", "bitscore"]

repl = blast[blast.pident > 95]

print(repl)

#substituion dataframe

newfile = []
count = 0

for rec in SeqIO.parse("concatenate_0035_0042_aa2.fa", "fasta"):
    #get corresponding value for record ID from dataframe
    x = repl.loc[repl.seq == rec.id, "Busco_ID"]
    #change record, if not empty
    if x.any():
        rec.name = rec.description = rec.id = x.iloc[0]
        count += 1
    #append record to list
    newfile.append(rec)

#write list into new fasta file
SeqIO.write(newfile, "changedtest.faa", "fasta")
#tell us, how hard you had to work for us
print("I changed {} entries!".format(count))
```

And I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Get_busco_blast.py", line 74, in <module>
    x = repl.loc[repl.seq == rec.id, "Busco_ID"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'seq'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do this with something like [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).

First create a dictionary

```
names = Series(df['seq name'].values,index=df['New seq name']).to_dict()
```

Now iterate

```
from Bio import SeqIO
outs = []
for record in SeqIO.parse("orig.fasta", "fasta"):
    record.id = names.get(record.id, default=record.id)
    outs.append(record)
SeqIO.write(open("new.fasta", "w"), outs, "fasta")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help, the first ligne of the script seemn to does not work, maybe there is a problem with a ) or somethign like that?

Comment: @Benjamin Fixed a typo.

Comment: Thanks you for you help :)

Comment: @Benjamin You're very welcome. Good luck with your FASTA.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [`Biopython`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc6) installed, then you can use `SeqIO` to read/write fasta files:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

#substituion dataframe
repl = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([["seqB_3652_i36", "Bob"], ["seqC_123_6XXX1", "Patrick"]]), columns = ["seq", "newseq"])

newfile = []
count = 0

for rec in SeqIO.parse("test.faa", "fasta"):
    #get corresponding value for record ID from dataframe
    #repl["seq"] and "newseq" are the pandas column with the old and new sequence names, respectively
    x = repl.loc[repl["seq"] == rec.id, "newseq"]
    #change record, if not empty
    if x.any():
        #append old identifier number to the new id name
        rec.name = rec.description = rec.id = x.iloc[0] + rec.id[rec.id.index("_"):]
        count += 1
    #append record to list
    newfile.append(rec)

#write list into new fasta file
SeqIO.write(newfile, "changedtest.faa", "fasta")
#tell us, how hard you had to work for us
print("I changed {} entries!".format(count))
```

Please note that this script doesn't check for multiple entries in the substitution table. It just takes the first element or doesn't change anything, if the record id is not in the dataframe.

Comment: I put a comment above, I got an issue, thanks for your help

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, because I don't have your file. But `repl.seq`, which you could also write as `repl["seq"]`, refers to the pandas column named "seq". Probably the dataframe you generate has a different column name for the ids you want to substitute. Maybe "qseqid". Then the script would have to be changed to `repl.qseqid` or `repl["qseqid"]`. Please always provide [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please delete your answer above, you should edit your question instead.

Comment: Oh yes, it works thank you so much :), do you know if it is now possible to add this new seq ID but to keep at the end the `_number_number `part ? for exemple if the old seq name was `g134554t1_0035_0042`and to transform it in `newseqname_0035_0042`? and for exemple `g45566.t1_0035_0035` into `newseqname_0035_0035` etc?

Comment: I am not familiar with the nomenclature. But if it always starts with an underscore `_`, you can retrieve the old id with rec.id, find the first appearance with `.index("_")`, slice the old id at this position with `id[index:]` and concatenate this part to the new name before assigning it to the sequence field.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not manage to do it, I'm not sur where those part go in the script. Could you add it on your first script you think? and yes it always sarts with an underscore ideed.

Comment: Usually, you are supposed to ask a new question, when you have a new problem. But since this is just a short addition to the code, here you go.

Comment: Thank you Mr. T it was very kind.